# How to check pointer of inherited class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Let's assume that we have two class: a polymorhpic class A and class B that inherits from class A. How can I check if a pointer of class A points to an object of class B?

Comment: I'm forced to wonder why you need to do this.

Comment: I cannot understand why this question got so many upvotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the [*runtime type information* (RTTI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) is enabled, you can cast the pointer to `B*` using `dynamic_cast`, and see if you get a non-null value back:

```
A* ptr = ... // some pointer
if (dynamic_cast<B*>(ptr)) {
    // ptr points to an object of type B or any type derived from B.
}
```

Another way of doing this would be using `typeid`:

```
if (typeid(*ptr) == typeid(B)) {
    // ptr points to an object of type B, but not to a type derived from B.
}
```

Note: if you need to do this often, good chances are that your design can be improved.

Comment: You should clarify that dynamic_cast will check that the pointer is to an object of type B or derived from B, and that typeid will check against just B.

Comment: @BenPope Thank you very much for a thoughtful comment! I edited the answer to comment on this difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dynamic_cast`.

```
void foo(A* aPtr);
{
   if ( dynamic_cast<B*>(aPtr) != NULL)
   {
     // Got a B.
   }
}

void bar()
{
   B b;
   foo(&b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not wanting to spoil the fun, but an initialized `enum` member in the base class would also do in case no `RTTI` is available.

I was thinking the other day, that in these classical OOP problems, one could also use a `variant` class, say:

```
variant<Tiger, Cat, Frog, Dog> object;
```

These classes might all inherit, say from `Animal`, one would not need virtual functions in the implementation at all, but would need to check for the type, the instance of which the `variant` contains, at runtime.

Comment: In that case, it's better to have a downcast function `virtual B* toB() {return 0;}` defined in A, and override it with `virtual B* toB() {return this;}` in B. This is better than an `enum` because it does not require the use of a second channel beside the v-table which might get out of sync, and consequently is less error prone.

Comment: Yeah, that's also a possibility, unless you can't afford virtual functions either.